# Animate height change from the top edge of a widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to change the height of a widget by moving the top edge (with the bottom, left, and right edges staying fixed). However I haven't been able to do this; I tried `SizeTransition`, `AnimatedPositioned`, `AnimatedSize`, and many combinations thereof, but every time the bottom edge seems to move instead of the top. I'd imagine there's some way to do this, seeing as how in Android and iOS layout constraints make these things fairly trivial. Has anyone been able to implement this?

Comment: Can you share your current code what you've tried so far?

Comment: @Manuel Actually figured this out––posting an answer

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to this. Wrapping `AnimatedContainer` in a `Positioned` element worked, here's the code:

```
Positioned(
  bottom: 0,
  child: AnimatedContainer(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    height: cardHeight, // Varies
    child: Stack(
      children: _buildContent(),
    ),
  ),
),
```